# Identify text data in image to read mm/dd, description and amount using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, expression, ocr

[image]

import re
    import cv2
    import pytesseract
    from pytesseract import Output
    from PIL import Image

```
from pytesseract import image_to_string

img = cv2.imread('/home/cybermakarov/Desktop/1.Chase Bank-page-002.jpg')
d = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type=Output.DICT)
keys = list(d.keys())


date_pattern = '^(0[1-9]|[12]|[1-9]|3[02])/'
Description_pattern='([0-9]+\/[0-9]+)|([0-9]+)|([0-9\,\.]+)'


n_boxes = len(d['text'])
for i in range(n_boxes):
    if int(d['conf'][i]) > 60:
        if re.match(description_pattern, d['text'][i]):
            (x, y, w, h) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i], d['width'][i], d['height'][i])
            detect_img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 300, 0), 2)

crop_img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

cv2.imshow('img',img)
#cv2.imshow("Cropped",  crop_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Please help me to identify date, description and amount using regular expressions,
i really tried hard to identify these pattern but could not. Second
 thing is that I want to crop image when code identifies the date,
 description and amount.

following is my image:

[image]

Comment: You need to preprocess the image to remove the horizontal lines before you can apply OCR. Can you add the input image to the post?

Comment: this is actual image on which i did simple detection using open with regix as you could see in my code.

Comment: For us to help you we need sample images to work with, please add the image that you're trying to OCR on, not a screenshot for your workspace

Comment: @nathancy added original image.

Answer (score 1):

To identify the text in the image, you must preprocess the image. To do this, we can remove the horizontal and vertical grid lines then throw the image into Pytesseract OCR. Here's the detected lines to be removed highlighted in green:

[image]

Result

[image]

Output from Pytesseract

```
ELECTRONIC WITHDRAWALS

DATE DESCRIPTION AMOUNT
01/02 Merchant Service Merch Fee 8030996550 CCD ID: 1841010148 $34.30
01/03 Authnet Gateway Billing 104820413 CCD ID: 1870568569 22.95
01/04 01/04 Online Transfer To Mma ...4622 Transaction#: 7794410276 200.00
01/08 01/08 Online Payment 7732727073 To Cleaning Connoisseur 300.00
01/11 01/11 Online Payment 7744233248 To Ramsey Sweis 148.80
01/11 01/11 Online Transfer To Mma ...4622 Transaction#: 7816805988 200.00
01/11 01/11 Payment To Chase Card Ending IN 2342 500.00
01/11 Aqaba Holdings, Inahl-51 Ahl-51 CCD ID: 1113720048 1,441.21
01/14 01/12 Payment To Chase Card Ending IN 2342 1,000.00
01/14 01/12 Online Transfer To Mma ...4622 Transaction#: 7841026719 1,000.00
01/16 01/16 Payment To Chase Card Ending IN 2342 1,000.00
01/16 01/16 Online Payment 7852542882 To Oakhurst Golf & Country Club 495.00
01/17 01/17 Online Payment 7762351731 To Ramsey Sweis 399.05
01/18 01/18 Online Transfer To Mma ...4622 Transaction#: 7837118990 200.00
01/18 Small Business Icpayment PPD ID: 1131414876 302.24
01/22 01/21 Payment To Chase Card Ending IN 2342 1,000.00
01/23 01/23 Payment To Chase Card Ending IN 2342 1,000.00
01/25 01/25 Online Payment 77868551 17 To Lv Office Limited Partnership 644.40
```

Code

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
result = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find horizontal lines
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (35,1))
detect_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)

# Find vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,15))
detect_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)

data = pytesseract.image_to_string(result, lang='eng',config='--psm 6')
print(data)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Very nice, it improved the detection accuracy but the next issue is not finding all the dates, i need logic for regular expression for description and amount and third is that i need to crop detected dates, description and amount so i could pass it to tesseract.

Comment: All the dates from OCR are printed to the console, I'm not sure what you mean by finding all the dates. Once you have the data, you can perform filtering to obtain the desired text. This answer is only to help you extract the data in the image into a string format which you can then apply additional processing on.

Comment: i am getting all the data using tesseract in single so its difficult to make segmentation dates, description and amount. I want to find all relevant data so that i could insert into excel sheets.